# I want to get the value of checkbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

In a table there are multiple rows, what I want is if I click on a particular name of user like "Sam" and "Adem"  I want to get the value of checkbox which only relates to that row.

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Select</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>Rank</td>
    <td>Address</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="1"></td>
    <td>Sam</td>
    <td>Sam001</td>
    <td>Admin</td>
    <td>XYZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="2"></td>
    <td>Adem</td>
    <td>Adem002</td>
    <td>Manager</td>
    <td>ZYZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: `this` (or `Event#target`), `closest()` and `find()` are the tools you need for this job.

Comment: Welcome to SO, btw. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: `$("td").click(function() { alert($(this).closest("tr").find("input[type='checkbox']").val(); })` - but you *probably* want to know if it's checked or not rather than "get the value", as all your examples have `value="1"` - so just `function getCheckboxVaue() { return "1"; }` would be easier...

Comment: $('tr td:nth-of-type(2)').click(function(){
               var val= $(this).parent('tr').find('td :input').val();
               alert(val);
            })   I hvae done this and it's working....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Attach click event on TD elements. In the handler find the checkbox using [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent) and [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find) methods. When you have found the checkbox, get its value using [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

Comment: It's unlikely that the checkbox will be a parent of a TD... which your statement implies.   You probably meant:   find the row using .parent and the checkbox using .find - would have been clearer with some code or a snippet using OPs html.  But question itself is low quality.

Comment: @freedomn-m

If you read carefully, I not only mentioned the `.parent()` method but also the `.find()` one. That is, it first finds the TR (`.parent()`) and then the CHECKBOX (`.find()`). I didn't add sample code because he didn't show the code he wrote.

Comment: No, if you read carefully, you *clearly* state *attach click event on TD, find the checkbox using .parent* - no mention of the tr - hence my statement that parent on the td won't find the checkbox.   What you may or may not have *meant* is irrelevant.

Comment: @freedomn-m

It wasn't really necessary to mention that TR is the ancestor of TD. That's a truism that can be omitted without prejudice to the understanding of the message.

Comment: `$('tr td:nth-of-type(2)').click(function(){
               var val= $(this).parent('tr').find('td :input').val();
               alert(val);
            })`    I hvae done this and it's working.

Comment: It can also work without TR tag and using `:checkbox` selector: `$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').val();`